# Pandas: how to merge rows by union of intervals

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, intervals

I'm a bit lost with pandas: I want to be able to merge an interval column by taking the union of intervals where the event is the same, but only doing this for seperated annotators. For example, my input would be this:

```
annotator  event          interval_presence
3          birds          [0,5]
3          birds          [7,9]
3          voices         [1,2]
3          traffic        [1,7]
5          voices         [4,7]
5          voices         [5,10]
5          traffic        [0,1]
```

Where each item in "interval_presence" is a list. I want this as an output:

```
annotator  event          interval_presence
3          birds          [[0,5],[7,9]]
3          voices         [1,2]
3          traffic        [1,7]
5          voices         [4,10]
5          traffic        [0,1]
```

I've seen that I can use the python library "piso" to merge intervals, but I don't know how to merge my intervals only on different events and on different annotators. Have you got any idea on how merge my intervals like this ?

Comment: what is "piso"?

Comment: It's a library that has been created to handle some operations on pandas intervals class: https://pypi.org/project/piso/

Comment: so are you asking how to use piso or how to reimplement this part of its functionality?

Comment: it's more how to implrement merging on a specific column using piso, I've edited my question

Comment: OK. that starts to clarify things. When you tried to do this, what happened? What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following example data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'annotator': [3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5],
    'event': ['birds', 'birds', 'voices', 'traffic', 'voices', 'voices', 'traffic'],
    'interval_presence': [[0,5], [7,9], [1,2], [1,7], [4,7], [5,10], [0,1]]
})
```

This code transfers the lists into intervals:

```py
data['interval_presence'] = data['interval_presence'].apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*x))
```

And this groups and then applies piso.union to the intervals:

```py
data = data.groupby(['annotator', 'event'])['interval_presence'] \
    .apply(pd.arrays.IntervalArray) \
    .apply(piso.union) \
    .reset_index()
```

Though, it seems that piso currently only supports intervals that are either left or right closed. There may be a deeper reason for this, but it may also just be out of date. For example, creating the intervals like this instead:

```py
data['interval_presence'] = data['interval_presence'].apply(lambda x: pd.Interval(*x), closed='both')
```

Will obtain an `AttributeError`: 'str' object has no attribute 'closed'.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a good example for a *supercombo* of [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`itertools.groupy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) :

```
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import groupby​

# df["interval_presence"] = df["interval_presence"].apply(literal_eval) #uncomment this line if string literal
​​
def merge_overintervals(ser):
    ser.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    return [next(i) for _, i in groupby(ser, key=lambda x: x[1])]
​
out = df.groupby(["annotator", "event"], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(list)
​
out["interval_presence"] = out["interval_presence"].apply(merge_overintervals)
```

​
Outupt :

```
print(out)

   annotator    event interval_presence
0          3    birds  [[0, 5], [7, 9]]
1          3   voices          [[1, 2]]
2          3  traffic          [[1, 7]]
3          5   voices         [[4, 10]]
4          5  traffic          [[0, 1]]
```

*NB : If you need to get a flatten 1-element list when nested, add this :*

```
from itertools import chain

out["interval_presence"]  = [x if len(x)>1 else list(chain(*x)) 
                             for x in out["interval_presence"]]
```