# Pandas: apply different custom functions to different columns when using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to be able to use a "groupby" on my pandas dataframe using different custom functions for each columns. For example, if I have this as input:

```
annotator  event          interval_presence   duration
3          birds          [0,5]               5
3          birds          [7,9]               10
3          voices         [1,2]               10
3          traffic        [1,7]               7
5          voices         [4,7]               4
5          voices         [5,10]              6
5          traffic        [0,1]               4
```

Where each item in "interval_presence" is a pandas interval. When merging, I want to take the mean of column "duration" and I want to use "pd.arrays.IntervalArray" and "piso.union" on my intervals in "interval_presence". So this would be the output:

```
annotator  event          interval_presence   duration
3          birds          [[0,5],[7,9]]       7.5
3          voices         [1,2]               10
3          traffic        [1,7]               7
5          voices         [4,10]              5
5          traffic        [0,1]               4
```

Right now, I know how to merge my intervals thanks to the answer in the post:
[Pandas: how to merge rows by union of intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75261213/pandas-how-to-merge-rows-by-union-of-intervals/75261825#75261825). So the solution would be:

```
data = data.groupby(['annotator', 'event'])['interval_presence'] \
    .apply(pd.arrays.IntervalArray) \
    .apply(piso.union) \
    .reset_index()
```

But how can I simultaneously apply a "mean" function to "duration" ?

Comment: Use `groupby.agg` with a `{'colname': function}` dictionary.

Comment: I've seen that I can use .agg, but what's the syntax when using custom functions ? Because something like `df = df.groupby(['annotator', 'event'])['interval_presence'].agg({ 
                         'interval_presence':'.apply(pd.arrays.IntervalArray).apply(piso.union)', 
                         'duration':'mean'}).reset_index()` isn't a good syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong `agg` syntax. Try this:

```py
df.groupby(["annotator", "event"]).agg({
    "interval_presence": lambda s: piso.union(pd.arrays.IntervalArray(s)),
    "duration": "mean"
})
```

Within the lambda, `s` is a series of `pd.Interval` objects.